# Greedy algorithm, error : expected identifer

Tags: algorithm, greedy

So I'm writing code for a class, and the job is to create a greedy algorithm. I wrote code that should work, but I'm getting an error code. Did I forget a {} somewhere or what's wrong here? The exact error is :

practice.c:14:9: error: expected identifier or '('
do
^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 errors generated
make: *** [: practice] Error 1

So that's my code

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int calculate_quarters(int cents);
int calculate_dimes(int cents);
int calculate_nickels(int cents);
int calculate_pennies(int cents);
int answer(void);
int quarters(void);
int dimes(void);
int nickels(void);
int pennies(void);
int main(void);
    do
    {
        int cents = get_int("How much change? \n");

        return cents;
    }
    while (cents <= 0)

    int quarters = 0;
    do
    {
        cents = cents - 25;
        quarters++;
    }
    while (cents >=25)
    return quarters;
    return cents;
    int dimes = 0;
    do
       {
        cents = cents - 10;
        dimes++;
        }
    while (cents >= 10)

    return dimes;
    return cents;
    int nickels = 0;
    do

    {
        cents = cents -5;
        nickels++;
    }
    while (cents >= 5)
    return nickels;
    return cents;
    int pennies = 0;
    do
    {
        cents = cents - 1;
        pennies++;
    }
     while (cents > 0)

    return pennies;
    return cents;
    do
    {
        printf("Quarters amount: &i\n" quarters);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Dimes amount: &i\n" dimes);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Nickels amount: &i\n" nickels);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Pennies amount: &i\n" pennies);
        printf("\n");
    }
    while (cents = 0)
```

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post all of the code in a single code block, so that people reading the question can copy/paste/compile the code, and see the error for themselves.

Comment: You should tell us what line you're getting the error on. And also what exactly the error is.

Comment: You don't terminate `do…while` statements, list `return` statements, mix pennies and cents. (There's an algorithm logic problem waiting.)

Comment: What problem is there with the do...while statements ? They were given with the problem.